# Kendo MVC Grid Dynamic Columns sorting in C#

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, columnsorting

I have dynamic grid column data like
Code (string)| Name(string | Account Data(Percentage format)
sorting working on Code and Name columns but click on Account data column its not working properly
output sorting of is -5.6%,-4.9%,2.6%,-1.4%,1.2%,etc. When i need result sorting like -5.6%,-4.9%,-1.4%,2.6%,1.2%,etc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKBed.png)
Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide code for your working code, and add the `[kendo-grid]` and `[c#]` tags.  Likely, you will need to sort the internal data by omitting the `%` in the displayed text.

Comment: Hi Mark, I added tags and i use Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>.columns and one of the column need to sorting , it is sorting but not perperly which i describe. :)